# C++ class needs to have variable number of references to objects of another class

Tags: c++, templates, reference, variadic-templates

Let's say I have a C++ class (class A) which needs to have references to variable number of instances of another class (class B). The needed number of references is known at compile time. As far as the usage I would like to have the ability to pass the references to the B type objects to the A type object at compile time.

I have been thinking about how to solve that problem and one idea which I have is to use variadic template construct. I am not very familiar with variadic templates so before studying that topic I would like to know whether it is good solution for my problem.

Comment: When you say "reference" what do you mean by that? It's not enough to have an array of `B` *objects* in the `A` class? What is the actual problem having these "references" supposed to solve? Why do you need them? And why do you say they have to be "references"?

Comment: Simply use an array of -- potentially smart -- pointers and assign the addresses whenever it is convenient.

Comment: Could you use a `std::shared_ptr` instead of references `A&`?

Comment: Study it anyway. You'll need to know how to do it later. `shared_ptr` is cool, but it does have overhead and should only be used when the ownership of the pointed-at object really is shared. And it rarely is. Prefer `unique_ptr`.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica thank you for your response. Do I understand correctly that you suggest to construct the array of pointers via non-type template argument usage?

Comment: @L3sek Yes. I don't see a need for templates really; keep it simple.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica I am sorry but I don't see the solution for the variable number of references (or pointers or ...) known at compile time.

Comment: I think you might need to take some time to consider the ownership semantics of the objects. Who should own them? Why should that entity own them? How can these object be shared from the owner?

Comment: What's wrong with A just having an `std::vector<shared_ptr<B>>` member ?

Comment: As for the template part, do you want to "pass" the object (or pointers to them) as template arguments? As in `A<&some_b_object, &another_b_object>`? Why? What problem is *that* supposed to solve?

Comment: @L3sek "Variable" and "compile time" are moderately contradictory. If the size is known at compile time there will be a define or const size_t somewhere; whether that's a template parameter or used as an array size right away is irrelevant. (OK, if you try to write a generally usable library it may be better to use a template parameter so that the code doesn't have to be touched. But in a one-off integrated program it should not matter.)

Comment: @L3sek Are you looking for sometzhing like this?

Comment: @SimonKraemer I don't see any link in your comment.

Comment: @L3sek Without having any of your code to look at it's hard to say what the best approach would be. [This](https://godbolt.org/z/fn9cPsjrc) could perhaps be one way.

Comment: @L3sek https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/zdTPPjKf7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The references should probably be (smart) pointers or `std::ref` objects. I use regular pointers for brevity. Depending on how exactly you want to pass them to the constructor, you can do this:

```
template <std::size_t nobj> class A
{
    std::array<B*, nobj> bs;
  public:
    // 1 Pass as separate arguments
    template <typename ... T>
    A(T* ... t) : bs{t...} {
       // check that the number of arguments is ok
       static_assert(nobj == sizeof ...(T));
    }
    // 2 Pass as an array
    A(const std::array<B*, nobj>& bs) : bs(bs) {}
};

// deduce the template parameter from the number of arguments
template<typename ... T>
A(T... t) -> A<sizeof ... (T)>;
```

so you can do initialisation both like this:

```
A a{&b1, &b2, &b3};
```

and like this:

```
std::array<B, 3> bs{&b1, &b2, &b3};
A a(bs);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is it possible to use the code above also in C++11?

Comment: @L3sek Yes, but only without the deduction guide. Template deduction guides were only introduced in C++17. [Click here for a live demo of the code above with C++11!](https://wandbox.org/permlink/AjLBWCkHue1I2PlZ).